# Insertion sort stops working after million input

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, input, insertion-sort

I have implemented insertion sort which is fine I guess.It reads from a file and sort them properly for input 10,100,1000,10000,10000.

However, when I gave a million for input, it does nothing. I even waited for 10 minutes to check if it was too slow.
I dynamically created my array and also tried merge sort with this. It worked perfecly fine with a million input but I could not understand why only insertion sort algorithm does not work with a million input.Here is a part of the code does the job;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void InsertionSort(int* array, int& size);
int main()
{
    int size;
    ifstream myfile("data.txt");
    myfile.open("data.txt");
    cout << "How many elements do you want to read" << endl;
    cin >> size;

    int* array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        myfile >> array[i];
    }

    InsertionSort(array, size);
    delete[] array;
}
void InsertionSort(int* array, int& size)
{
    int temp, j;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j - 1];
            array[j - 1] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just attach a debugger then I guess and look what it does. If it still is in your sorting routine it takes long. Or just keep it running for a few hours and check back later.

Comment: @Hayt Thank you, I will try. hope everybody would be kind as you are. Everyone is trying to prove something here instead of helping anyone

Comment: @G.Rust FWIW, I think your question is appropriate for SO. If you want people to give you tips/best practices, I invite you to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise, keep posting here. :)

Comment: I'm confused why this is downvoted. Sure, the code's not the best and the post could use some formatting, but the question itself seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @GManNickG think so but they though it was useless and banned me from questioning for a while because of this..

Answer (score 9):

Your program is running in O(n²) time, since you have two nested loops that both depend on the size of the input. So once you go from 10,000 to 1,000,000 elements, your program will take 100² = ten thousand times longer to complete. Furthermore, it can be that your dataset fit in the processor's cache before, but with 1 million elements it no longer does, so this will slow it down even more.

O(n²) algorithms make things go very slow very quickly. With an input size of 10⁶, it means your program will take in the order of 10¹² operations to complete. Assuming your processor runs at a few 10⁹ operations per second at most, and that your algorithm will surely use more than one operation per step, it will take more than 10³ seconds for your program to complete.

Comment: It still needs to show me some output when I try to print array after sorting. It never does. @G.Sliepen

Comment: The algorithm is not growing cubically.

Comment: @G.Rust Assuming there is a triple loop: How do you know you waited long enough? Apparently you did not wait until the program ends. As someone else told you already, going from 10K to 1M with O(n^3) is 10000 times slower.

Comment: Well, it looked like an MCVE to me before. But I adjusted my answer. It still takes a lot of time.

Comment: Isn't it complexity O(n²) for the sorting? Is it normal that it should keep waiting that long? I mean it has been 20 min just for the 1 million input @deviantfan

Comment: `Isn't it complexity O(n²) for the sorting?` Uh no. It depends on the algo / general idea *and on your code*.

Comment: @G.Rust that is usually the point of implementing the sorting yourself and test with so many data. So you see and "feel" how differently O(n²) is compared to O(n*log n)

Comment: @Hayt I tried to compare 10000 and 10000 input with the insertion sort algorithm. There is not much time difference between them but when I pass a million input. The program keeps working...

Comment: @G.Rust just to to iterate "slowly" toward the 1Mio. you will see it. like 200k. then 300k etc.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort is O(n lg(n)) in the worst case, insertion sort is quadratic on average (not only in the worst case).
The difference is huge.

Suppose that you had two algoritms, A and B.

For any input of size n, A takes n<sup>2</sup> operations, while B takes n*lg(n) operations.

If you double the input, algorithm A takes (2n)<sup>2</sup> = 4n<sup>2</sup> operations - four times as many.

B takes 2n * lg(2n) = 2n * (lg(n) + 1) = 2n * lg(n) + 2 = 2(n * lg(n) + 1), which is just a tiny bit more than twice as many.

To illustrate the difference when you go from 10,000 to 1,000,000 elements (using ten-logarithms for simplicity):

```
10,000 * 10,000 = 100,000,000 
1,000,000 * 1,000,000 = 1,000,000,000,000
```

That's 10,000 times as much.

```
10,000 * log(10,000) = 40,000
1,000,000 * log(1,000,000) = 6,000,000
```

That's 150 times as much.

So it's not unexpected that, if the ten thousand case takes approximately the same amount of time, insertion sort will take much longer than merge sort for the million case.